# How do I view a directory within a site that has wordpress without running into WP 404 error?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installed on my main directory. I've created a /test directory that has nothing to do with the WordPress site. Just a folder to do some dev stuff. When I visit the URL in the browser I get a 404 error from WordPress. I figure it's the .htaccess file. How do I allow requests to go through to the /test folder and view the file content.

.htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `/test/.htaccess` with this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This will neutralize all the rewrite rules create by main WP .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok one more try: Insert `RewriteRule ^test(/|$) - [L]` just below `RewriteBase /` in main .htaccess